# Creating JSON object from Ienumerable using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml, json.net

I am trying to use LINQ to JSON to create a JSON object using the http://james.newtonking.com/json (JSON.NET) framework.

Basically I am trying to create a certain structure from the IEnumerable output. Have something like Products-> Actual,forecast,Target.

The LINQ to XML statement works fine and I can see the result. Is it due to deferred execution and lazy evaluation in LINQ to XML? If yes, how do I solve it.

This is what my LINQ to XML method looks like

```
IEnumerable resultSet = (xmlDoc.Root.Descendants(ns + "Row").Select(result => new
        {
            MonthYearShortName = (DateTime)result.Element(ns + "Column0"),
            Product = (String)result.Element(ns + "Column1"),
            Actual = (decimal)result.Element(ns + "Column2"),
            Forecast = (decimal)result.Element(ns+"Column3"),
            Target = (decimal)result.Element(ns + "Column4"),
        }));
```

And this is my LINQ to JSON. The example I am using comes from http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/CreatingLINQtoJSON.htm

```
JObject rss =
                resultSet.Select(p => new JObject(p.Product,
                    new JProperty("MonthYearShortName", p.MonthYearShortName),
                    new JProperty("Actual", p.Actual),
                    new JProperty("Forecast", p.Forecast),
                    new JProperty("Target", p.Target)));

            Console.WriteLine(rss.ToString());
```

When I execute the LINQ to JSON statements I get the below error message

```
Error   5   'System.Collections.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' could be found
```

My usings

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Extensions = System.Xml.Linq.Extensions;
```

Not really sure why I am unable to do a select in the second LINQ to JSON statement.

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Just checking....do you have a reference to System.Linq?

Comment: what if you change JObject rss .... to var rss instead? I'm thinking error might be because resultSet.Select(...) is selecting a list of objects rather than a single object

Comment: Nope, that doesn't solve it either :(

Comment: Are you trying to get the JSON string from the deserialized xml?

Comment: yes, I am trying to create a JSON string.

Comment: Do you mean something like `["Product1": { "Actual": 20, "Forecast": 21, "Target": 39 }, "Product2": { "Actual": 50, "Forecast": 51, "Target": 69 }] ?

Comment: That is not a valid `JSON` string.

Answer (score 2):

The Select extension method is defined on the generic `IEnumerable<T>` interface (not the non-generic `IEnumerable`).

For the code to compile, you will need to first call `Cast<>()`

```
JObject rss =
         resultSet.Cast<XElement>().Select(p => new JObject(p.Product,
                    new JProperty("MonthYearShortName", p.MonthYearShortName),
                    new JProperty("Actual", p.Actual),
                    new JProperty("Forecast", p.Forecast),
                    new JProperty("Target", p.Target)));

            Console.WriteLine(rss.ToString());
```

(or convert to a generic `IEnumerable<resultSet>` in some other way)

Comment: now I am facing a 

The name 'Cast' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Navyseal I edited my answer, you might need to tweak that code, because I haven't tested

Comment: Still no luck man. The properties (p.Product and the rest) are not available. I get an error "Cannot resolve symbol"

Comment: @Navyseal does it compile now? I am not sure what to pass to the cast to be honest resultSet.Cast<TResult>().Select

Answer (score 0):

This code should work if you are trying to get the `JSON` string:

```
 var resultSet = (xmlDoc.Root.Descendants("Row").Select(result => new
        {
            MonthYearShortName = (DateTime)result.Element(ns + "Column0"),
            Product = (String)result.Element("Column1"),
            Actual = (decimal)result.Element("Column2"),
            Forecast = (decimal)result.Element("Column3"),
            Target = (decimal)result.Element("Column4"),
        }));

 var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultSet);
 Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Comment: I know this one. its just that I need to change the structure of the string first. Basically have something like Products-> Actual,forecast,Target

Comment: Can you post in your question what is the format of the string you expect to get?